# FileExistsError: [WinError 183] Cannot create a file when that file already exists:

Tags: python-2.7

i when run this test program create the below error.

```
import shutil    
src=r"G:\aaa"     
dst=r"F:\zzz"    
shutil.copytree(src,dst, symlinks=False, ignore=None)
```

FileExistsError: [WinError 183] Cannot create a file when that file already     exists:

**but the the folder of F:\zzz is empty!!!**

Comment: Need more information. What is code for the test program? Fromm the output it seems that a call to some File IO API is throwing this error when trying to create a file which is already present. Need to see code for more information.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre the `r` before the string takes care of this

Comment: @Milk: true. My eyes aren't working so well this late :) good for OP. If I had a dollar when someone falls for that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Cannot create a file when that file already exists" is a generic Windows message which is confusing because it's the same for directories or regular files. (Windows isn't known for very helpful error messages, you have to make do with that)

from the online help of `shutil.copytree`:

```
>>> help(shutil.copytree)
```

> Help on function copytree in module shutil:
>
> copytree(src, dst, symlinks=False, ignore=None, copy_function=, ignore_dangling_symlinks=False)
>
> Recursively copy a directory tree.
>
> **The destination directory must not already exist.**

So first time it probably works, but other times you need to perform

```
shutil.rmtree(dst)
```

to remove the destination directory prior to copying the tree (note that Windows is annoying with permissions and that files with read-only attribute can choke `shutil.rmtree`, which I personally copied the code into a custom version (you're encouraged to do so in the online help) to add a `os.chmod(path,0o777)` prior to deleting regular files.

Comment: thanks. it is correct.I thought it would be created inside the folder. But it also created the folder itself

Comment: `OSError: [Errno 17] File exists: ` is the error in Python. So Python isn't better with error messages...

Comment: That's a windows message. You can trap the exception and add the currently processed filename to the exception message.

Answer (score 6):

*shutil.copytree(src, dst, symlinks=False, ignore=None, copy_function=copy2, ignore_dangling_symlinks=False, dirs_exist_ok=False)*

*dirs_exist_ok* dictates whether to raise an exception in case dst or any missing parent directory already exists.

**Python 3.8** now have support of dirs_exist_ok parameter. This won't give that error anymore and overwrite the destination folder in case it already exists.

Hence you need to use:

```
shutil.copytree(src, dst, dirs_exist_ok=True)
```

Comment: Is there an elegant solution like that for Python 3.7?