# "FileExistsError: Cannot create a file when that file already exists:" But can not find the file in the directory it's supposed to be

Tags: python-3.x, directory, copy, shutil

I'm attempting to copy a folder from one directory to another.

Here is the relevant bit of code:

```
import os
import shutil

def harvestSorter(path):
    interviews = os.listdir(path)
    for i in interviews:
        if i.endswith('SF1'):
            shutil.copytree(os.path.join(path, i), os.path.join(SFU1, i), symlinks=False, ignore=None)
```

Now, the code runs fine, however when I try to copy a file to a specific directory, I encounter the error mentioned in the title.

```
FileExistsError: Cannot create a file when that file already exists:
```

Claiming that the folder already exists in the target directory. However, when I go *to* that directory, the folder is not there.

I've found this answer: [FileExistsError: [WinError 183] Cannot create a file when that file already exists:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46061797/fileexistserror-winerror-183-cannot-create-a-file-when-that-file-already-exis)

However it didn't help much as it basically just says that the destination directory must not already exist.